# Unpredictable Unique Identifier

Tags: c#

For an application I am working on, I need to generate a session token which must have following properties:

- it should be unique for the application at least, globally unique would be even better
- it should be unpredictable
- it should not be too long, as it will have to be passed around in a http request header, so smaller is better

I was thinking about adapting a Guid structure with a cryptographic random number, but it may be an overkill. Anyone know/created a data structure that would fit all those properties?

Comment: Why not just use a Guid?

Comment: What's wrong with a regular guid?

Comment: Well, I need to ensure unpredictability. Regular guid is designed to be globally unique, not completely unpredictable.

Comment: I can only repeat the GUID recommendation. It's widely and easily available, as random and unique as you'll ever need it to be, and a meager 32-something byte *when formatted as text*. Why do you need to "ensure unpredictability"? I smell security through obscurity...

Comment: @Kel I would like to see you predict my guids

Comment: @delnan: GUIDs are not *guaranteed* to be *random* in any way. There are many reasons why Kel might want to ensure unpredictability in a session key. For examplle: if I can predict what session keys a widely-used web service is going to produce in the future then I can start working out *today* how to attack a session that might be using that key *tomorrow*.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Let me be very clear on this point. **All of the answers saying to use a GUID are deeply wrong and you should not under any circumstances do so.**

There is nothing whatsoever in the specification for GUIDs that requires that they be *unpredictable by attackers*. GUIDs are allowed to be sequential if allocated in blocks, GUIDs are allowed to be created with non-crypto-strength randomness, and GUIDs are allowed to be created from known facts about the world, like your MAC address and the current time.  **Nothing whatsoever requires that GUIDs be unpredictable.**

If you need an unpredictable session key then generate one using a crypto strength random number generator to make sufficiently many bits.

More generally: **use the right tool for the job** particularly when it comes to security-impacting code. GUIDs were designed to make sure that two companies did not accidentally give the same identifier to two different interfaces. If that's your application, use a GUID for it. **GUIDs were invented to prevent accidents by benign entities, not to protect innocent users against determined attackers.** GUIDs are like stop signs -- there to prevent accidental collisions, not to protect against attacking tanks.

GUIDs were *not* designed to solve any problem other than accident prevention, so **do not under any circumstances use them to solve crypto problems**. Use a crypto library specifically designed to solve your problem, and implemented by world-class experts.

Comment: Not a knock on your answer in the least, but there was also nothing in the original question pertaining to attackers.  I would go so far to say that by tossing out the word "unpredictable" on its own is incomplete in the nonspecification of the context.  Just as someone asks "Is this secure?", the right response is "Secure to what threat(s)?", I think the same tack can be taken here.  If the answer was "Unpredictable to a casual user", most GUID implementations are not problematical at all.  Against targeted attack?  You're spot on.  Jus' sayin.

Comment: It's also depends on the version of the Guid being created.  C# uses pinvoke/win32 UuidCreate which uses Version 4 for the creation of Guids which states it rely's on Random Numbers.  Unless I'm wrong, Random Numbers are unpredictable.  It's important for people to actually do research on how Microsofts implementation works and not state incorrect information, especially on stack overflow.  The myth that UuidCreate uses a MAC Address is spread around is incorrect.

Comment: @ErikPhilips: v4 guids are not guaranteed to be *crypto strength random*, and some of the bits are not random at all. My point is **do not use something designed for uniqueness as a source of unpredictability**. Use tools for the purposes for which they were designed.

Comment: @ErikPhilips I don't think `UuidCreate` is guaranteed to create v4 guids. While it is currently implemented like that that can change in the future. If you read the documentation you'll see that unpredictability is not guaranteed.

Comment: In my case, the piece of code that will generate the session token will not necessarily be deployed on a windows machine either, so the unpredictability should be guaranteed _by design_ for security purposes (it's a session token, it was obvious to me, but I should have specified that in the question, my bad).

Comment: `UuidCreate` creates V4 Guids since Windows 2000 or later. http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/553194.html. MSDN Documentation States: "The UuidCreate function generates a UUID that cannot be traced to to ethernet address of the computer on which it was generated. It also cannot be associated with other UUIDs created on the same computer. If you do not need this level of security, your application can use the `UuidCreateSequential` If you're really worried, Simply SHA-1 and truncate to 128 bits like UUID Version 5.

Comment: @ErikPhilips: And that is *still* not solving the problem of generating a session key. Guids, no matter how they are generated, are for *preventing collisions between benign entities*, not *protecting session contents from attackers.*  **When it comes to security, use the tool designed for the task at hand.** That is the smart and safe thing to do.

Answer (score 7):

You could use the cryptographic  [RandomNumberGenerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator.aspx) and get however many bytes you want to generate an identifier of suitable length.

```
    RandomNumberGenerator rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create();

    byte[] bytes = new byte[8];
    rng.GetBytes(bytes);

    // produces a string like "4jpKc52ArXU="
    var s = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

Comment: I'd use about 16 byte hashes. Collisions of 8 byte hashes become likely at a few billion entries. But the code itself is pretty much what I'd use.

Answer (score 3):

How about using [what ASP.NET uses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionidmanager.aspx) to generate unique, unpredictable and secure session ids:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.SessionState;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var request = new HttpRequest("", "http://localhost", "");
        var response = new HttpResponse(TextWriter.Null);
        var context = new HttpContext(request, response);
        var id = new SessionIDManager().CreateSessionID(context);
        Console.WriteLine(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's a little weird is that looking at `CreateSessionID` in Reflector, the HttpContext parameter is not used at all.  I'm guessing it's because `SessionIDManager` implements `ISessionIDManager` which implies there may be other `SessionIDManager`s available?

Comment: @Jesse C. Slicer, yes but as it is part of the interface all implementations take it as argument. Also in future implementations of the `SessionIDManagers` this could change so it is safer to provide it.

Comment: No disagreement there.  I would love to know the original justification, that's all.

Comment: Checked with reflector too, seems like the implementation is very simple indeed: it uses a RNGCryptoServiceProvider to generate 15 bytes and then encodes it to get a string.

Comment: @Kel, yeah, it's as simple as that. If you don't want to use the SessionIDManager you could simply *borrow* the code that it uses internally.

Comment: If you feel weird using a `SessionIDManager`, a 2nd alternative is to call `Path.GetRandomFileName()` one or more times.  That function also uses `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` and promises to return a cryptographically strong random 8.3 string.  Though really, adrift's answer is probably the way to go if you're implementing it yourself.

Comment: Yes, I simply used the `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` in order to generate 16 bytes identifier, the implementation is quite straightforward.

Comment: @Kel: If you're still worried about uniqueness, one simple adjustment you can make is to prepend something predictable but unique to your unpredictable session id.  Though the likelihood of collisions between a set of random 15 byte string is pretty low unless you have a very large set of them.

Answer (score 1):

If you really and truly must have unpredictability, then generate a `GUID` and use a 128-bit bit mixer to rearrange the bits. Probably best to use a 64-bit bit mixer to mix the high and low portions. And, yes, there are bit mixers that guarantee unique output for every unique input.

Note that this isn't *completely* unpredictable. If somebody watching knows that the value is an obfuscated GUID, then he can probably examine successive values and, with some effort, potentially reverse-engineer your bit mixer.