# Is it really dangerous to save hashed password in cookies?

Tags: security, authentication, cookies, logging, passwords

There are many discussions about security risk for saving hash password in cookies, as upon accessing to the user's computer, a hacker can log in with the saved password. If a hacker has access to the user's computer, he can catch the password, as browsers also save passwords locally (encrypted of course). What is the difference between password set in cookies with that saved by the browser?

For obvious reason, a temporary GUID should be send instead of password. In any case, I believe that limiting access to the logged IP can close doors for attackers to use locally saved GUID. Of course, it will limit the length of logged period, as IP is usually dynamic and regularly changes; but I think it is worth of its noticeable security. Any idea?

Comment: the only thing that makes a hashed password secure, is that the hashing happens on the server.

Comment: I know what you mean; but here the purpose of hashed password or GUID is to make a long term, which cannot be changed for try & error attack.

Comment: **[Do not use a guid as a session token.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7732540/unpredictable-unique-identifier/7733025#7733025)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose the reason why you would want to store a hashed password in a cookie is to create a "remember me" cookie. So you need a value for the cookie that is secret, so that not someone else could easily guess it. Anyone with access to this value would be able to log in as this user, so it is actually an "extra password".

There are two risks involved here:

Most important is the risk of exposing the password. This would not only put your site at risk, but potentially other sites as well. Most users re-use their password for everything, and the password would probably give an intruder access to both the users email account and netbank. Someone with access to the hashed value may use brute force or rainbow tables to discover the original password (rainbow tables are long lists of pre-calculated hashes). Rainbow tables are easily available for passwords up to more than 8 characters, and even longer. You may avoid this by salting the password so that it is i.e. more than 20 characters before you create the hash (remember to store the salt in the cookie as well). A properly salted password hash calculated with a safe hashing algorithm should be quite safe.

The other risk is connected to the fact that the user must change his original password to make the hashed password string invalid. It is impossible for the user to actually turn off this feature once it is turned on. You may delete the cookie when he un-checks the "remember me" button, but that will have no effect if the cookie already is compromised. What if his computer is i.e. stolen? If the user has checked this button on one computer then he must have access to that computer to disable this feature.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's less secure to use the hashed password in a cookie. There *is* a difference between saving it in the browser and sending it over the wire: unless you're always using SSL, an attacker doesn't need access to the machine to read the cookie out of the request.

It's much safer to send a random value, as then there's no tie to the user's actual password: it's possible to expire a session by forgetting the random value, without having to get the user to change their password.  Also if the attacker does get the hashed value out of the cookie, it may be possible for them to recover the actual password if that's what's sent.

Comment: It is not possible to recover the password from a hash value.Hash functions are one-way functions.If it is a really bad function and the attacker does some dictionary attack it may be possible to find a string that produces the same hash value.But the way you put it in your answer it is not clear what your last statement means

Comment: Functions that are generally good hash functions make bad functions for hashing passwords, as they are designed for speed.  It's becoming practical to attack low-quality passwords hashed with MD5, for example.  So I stand by my "may be possible", although I will admit I wasn't as clear as I could have been.

Comment: I am not sure I get what you mean by `good hash functions make bad functions for hashing passwords, as they are designed for speed`.o you mean that a function that is meant to be used for password, is expeced to be fast?

Comment: I mean that the faster your hash function runs, the less time it will take to brute-force any particular password.  Schemes like bcrypt are tunable, so you can ensure that it will take a long time to verify a password, this means that it will take much longer to brute-force it.  See http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/

Answer (score 1):

> as upon accessing to the user's computer, a hacker can log in with the
>   saved password. If a hacker has access to the user's computer, he can
>   catch the password, as browsers also save passwords locally (encrypted
>   of course).

Not sure what you mean here. If you ask IE to remember your password for a site and someone has the password to your computer and can use your IE then yes, he can log-in using your password. But this is not related to hashing or cookies etc.

First of all, a hashed password can not be retrieved. So if someone has the hash of your password, he does not know your password.

When you login to a site that requests a password, you provide the password which is send encrypted. The standard practice is to store the user's password as a hash i.e. not the password itself. So you type the password and the receiving server will compare the hash with the one stored.

Now related to your question on sending the hashed password inside a cookie, this is related to session management. I.e. to determine whether a user has already succesully loggedin or not.
IMHO using just the hashed-password as a way to determine if the user has already logged-in when using plain HTTP is not a good idea.

But if this what you ask, it is another topic.
I.e. how to best do session management over HTTP connections

Answer (score 1):

Times when you should ask the user to re-enter their password:

1. When they try to change their password.
2. When they try to change their email address.
3. When they try to change their security information (anything that can be used to recover their password, including username, email address, security question, etc.).
4. When they try to access highly secure account information and have not entered their password for more than 15 minutes or so (if all information is highly secure, you should flat out log them out for inactivity instead).  Amazon does this a lot.

Saving a hashed password makes this less effective.

As an aside, you should already be using cookies that are Secure (won't transmit over HTTP), HttpOnly (not accessible via javascript) to protect against XSS attacks.  Of course, if someone hacks the person's machine completely they'll just install a keylogger.